# Install latest version of QGis on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, repository, gis

I'n not an experienced user of Linux. But I just wanted to install the latest version of GRASS GIS and QGIS on Ubuntu 18.04. There are many different ways to do this I guess. There are the ppa's, there are the normal qgis-repositories for ubuntu and than there is also ubuntugis. It's all a little bit overwhelming and in the process of installing QGIS I think I messed some things up.

When I run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` I added these two repositories:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
```

Then I do all the steps provided here:

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

But when I run `sudo apt install qgis` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.10.2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.10.2+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.10.2+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the one time I tried to add the ppa. When I run `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, I get:

```
...
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-bionic.list
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-bionic.list.save
```

I just wanted to have the newest version of QGIS and GRASS (due to Python3) and now I don't know how to get back. Does anyone have a pointer?

Comment: »» I don't know how to get back «« : "Fix "broken" → `sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 2):

Probably not much different from what you did : 
The instructions listed here seem to work perfectly with Ubuntu 18.04 : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://qgis.org/debian bionic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'  
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Confirmed OK a few days ago here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207591/get-newer-version-of-qgis/1207664#1207664

And I tested with a newly updated Ubuntu 18.04 today : Please see the install result : `qgis3_Ubuntu1804.txt` → https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cw2z27h5q7sf51/qgis3_Ubuntu1804.txt?dl=0

Comment: thank you very much! I'll try it later today